WPF Saving really large control to bitmap results in partial image
I have a really large control that I want to save as a high-DPI TIFF image. The width is narrow, but the height of the control is the problem (it's usually inside a scroll view). The ActualHeight of the visual is around 25,000, which is over 78,000 pixels when adjusted for the requested DPI (300). The problem is that only the first 32,767 pixels are written and the rest of the TIFF image is blank. Obviously, the height is too large for the encoder because if I try the same thing on a jpeg format using a JpegBitmapEncoder, I get an error "System.ArgumentException: The image dimensions are out of the range supported by this codec". With the tiff, there is no explicit error, but the image is only partially written.
    public static BitmapSource GetImage(FrameworkElement control, int width, int height, int dpi)
    {
        var viewbox = new Viewbox();

        control.Width = width;
        control.Height = height;

        viewbox.Child = control;
        viewbox.Measure(new Size(width, height));
        viewbox.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
        viewbox.UpdateLayout();

        var dpiAdjustedWidth = dpi / 96.0 * width;
        var dpiAdjustedHeight = dpi / 96.0 * height;
        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)dpiAdjustedWidth, (int)dpiAdjustedHeight, dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Default);
        bitmap.Render(viewbox);

        return bitmap;
    }

    public static void SaveAsTiff(BitmapSource src, Stream outputStream)
    {
        var encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));

        encoder.Save(outputStream);
    }

Code is called like this:
    var bitmap = GetImage(control, width, height, dpi);
    using (var output = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
         SaveAsTiff(bitmap, output);
    }

The full error when trying JpegBitmapEncoder:
Error: 
The image dimensions are out of the range supported by this codec.
The bitmap size is outside the valid range. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F51)Details: 
System.ArgumentException: The image dimensions are out of the range supported by this codec. ---> 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The bitmap size is outside the valid range. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F51)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.SaveFrame(SafeMILHandle frameEncodeHandle, SafeMILHandle encoderOptions, BitmapFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.Save(Stream stream)

Is there an elegant way to chunk the bitmap and then merge the chunks into the final image? I'd like to avoid System.Drawing if possible.
The overflow happens inside of BitmapEncoder.SaveFrame. I tried splitting GetImage to produce multiple BitmapSource and then adding those as frames, but the result is just the first chunk of the image, so I don't think I'm using frames correctly. To be clear, the chunks need to be stitched vertically, and just adding them as frames doesn't define their position.
